# Problems with GCJ (jc1.exe)

Tags: java, exe, gcj

I not whether this is the sort of question to be asked on StackOverflow, but I'll ask it anyway.

I am using GCJ (as part of MinGW) on Windows XP SP3 to compile a Java class to an EXE.

The Java Class is:

```
public class Test

{

public static void main(String args[])
  {

    System.out.println("This is a test.");

   }

}
```

Now when I run GCJ with the Java source file, it fails with:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcj --main=Test Test.java
Test.java:0: error: malformed .zip archive in CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\lib\tools.jar/

jc1.exe: out of memory allocating 1342179073 bytes
```

I then compiled the Java class and run GCJ again, but once again it failed with:

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcj --main=Test Test.class

jc1.exe: out of memory allocating 1342179073 bytes
```

Why is it doing this and what can I do to make GCJ work?

Comment: I'm not an expert at this, but as far as I know gcj does not support Java 1.6. Try this again with Java 1.4.2 - that's the lastest that gcj can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have finally found an answer to the problem. It seems that there is a problem with the MinGW gcj as when I tried the Cygwin version everthing worked.

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution; this might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
gcj -g --main=Test -o Test Test.class
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work. I suspect Jesper is right; I need Java 1.4